# Intron's deletion from the given sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Below you can find the simple script for the introns detection along the given DNA sequence

```
from re import match

f= open('data.txt', 'r').readlines()[1::2]
u = [element[:-1] for element in f]
chain=u[0]
exons=[]

#detect introns in chains
for i in u:
    for j in range(len(chain)):
        if i==chain: #pass sequence itself
            pass
        else:
            if match(i, chain[j::]):
                print "Intron %s has been detected in %d position" % (i, j)
                #Statement for place selection consisted of chain without current intron to the exons list
```

where input data.txt consist of chain in upper instance and intron sub-strings as the further instances

```
>Rosalind_10 # chain
ATGGTCTACATAGCTGACAAACAGCACGTAGCAATCGGTCGAATCTCGAGAGGCATATGGTCACATGATCGGTCGAGCGTGTTTCAAAGTTTGCGCCTAG
>Rosalind_12 #intron
ATCGGTCGAA
>Rosalind_15 #intron
ATCGGTCGAGCGTGT
```

now I'm looking for the best definition of the slice statement which will select exon sequence only  (chain with deleted intron in found position)  in the each loop and place it to the exon lists. How It could be done easily ?

Thanks for help,

Gleb

Comment: you should ask http://biostars.org

Comment: Why don't iterate over the sequence and `if seq.startswith(exon) del sequence[i:len(exon)]`? Did you consider to use biopython to parse multifasta files?

Comment: Please take a careful look at the following item in the [FAQ of Rosalind](http://rosalind.info/faq/#can-i-post-my-solutions-somewhere): `However, please do not publish your code outside of the Rosalind website.` I know it's not technically *your* solution but it's a public solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply store the chain as a string and use the `str.split(intron)` this way you don't need to search for the positions and you can later join the remaining sequence with join.

I would do something like that, note that I simplify some expressions you use:

```
#This way of opening a document is better because you don't need the close() as in your code
# (which as you did it is easily forget)
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()[1::2] 
u = [element[:-1] for element in data]
chain = str(u[0]) #store as a string the chain 
exons = []

for intron in data:
    if intron == chain:
        continue
    else:
        exon = chain.split(intron) # Find the introns and delete them 
        exon= "".join(gene) # to get again a single chain
        exons.append(exon)
```

Note that this code will get as an intron the line ">Rosalind_12" so you should check for it (consider the statement `ifelse`)